# Copy and paste data and have it be updated automatically

Tags: vba, excel

So I created a copy and paste function. I had help previously with an error I encountered. However, I am now wanting to make the values copy and pasted to be updated when the original date is changed. So, my original thought was to paste something like `=(ws.Cells(i, j)`. And have a nested for loop to with the values `i` staying the same as below and `j` going in between 6 and 16. But I couldn't get that to work.

If there is a special paste function or something that I am unaware of that would be great. Is there a way to get copy and paste data but also have it still be reliant on the original (updates when the original is changed).

If there is another question with a solution to this problem then I didn't see it and I am sorry.

I have my code below. And any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Goals")
a = Worksheets("Goals").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

  If Worksheets("Goals").Cells(i, 20).Value = "Red" Then

  ws.Activate
  Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 6), ws.Cells(i, 16)) 'columns to be copied
  rng.Copy 
  Worksheets("Scorecard").Activate
  b = Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Worksheets("Scorecard").Cells(b + 1, 2).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Worksheets("Goals").Activate

  End If

Next


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Worksheets("Forms").Activate
Worksheets("Forms").Cells(22, 10).Select 'going back to the Forms page

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Worksheets("Goals").Range("I6:I16").Copy
Worksheets("Scorecard").Paste Link:=True
```

I hope you wont mind if the sheets switch in this process..

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that they will switch in this process? Also, I inserted your code and it didn't work at first. But I switched out just my paste line with yours and it seemed to work. But I am not sure what the switch is.

Comment: i mean it may switch focus from Goals to scorecard when you run the program. I haven't tested it but i am trying to recollect it form memory. But anyways Paste link will work for you issue.